# How to name select id element using jquery each looping?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I want to implement jquery select2 plugin into a form. I have a problem with naming the textbox so that the select2 can be triggered. Here is the html:

```
<select id="select1"></select>
<select id="select2"></select>
<select id="select3"></select>
```

And here is the code to retrieve data from database:

```
$('#select').select2({
        ajax: {
                url: "get_member.php",
                dataType: 'json',
                delay: 200,
                data: function (params) {
                    return {
                        q: params.term
                    };
                },
                processResults: function (data) {

                    return {
                        results: data
                    };
                },
                cache: true
            }
        });
```

How can I change the id element from select to select1, select2 etc? I read that it is possible to use jquery each loop but I don't know how.

Comment: `$('#select1,#select2,#select3').select2(.....)`

Comment: ^ or put a common class on all the elements: `$('.select').select2(...);`

Comment: @Satpal, I mean I want it programmatically. It's possible that there are 20 selects in the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## There are few ways

> **1. Wrap your selects or using form with id, so it became like this:**
>
> ### html
>
> ```
> <form id="niceform">
> <select id="select1"></select>
> <select id="select2"></select>
> <select id="select3"></select>
> </form>
> ```
>
> ### js
>
> ```
> $('#niceform select').select2({ ... });
> ```

Or

> **2. Use jQuery special selector:**
>
> ```
> $('select[id^=select]').select2({ ... });
> ```
>
> that will select all `select` element which have id attribute start with word "select"

Or

> **3. Give them classes:**
>
> ### html
>
> ```
> <select class="select" id="select1"></select>
> <select class="select" id="select2"></select>
> <select class="select" id="select3"></select>
> ```
>
> ### js
>
> ```
> $('.select').select2({ ... });
> ```

You don't need looping actually.

Answer (score 1):

using each loop

```
$('select[id^="select"]').each(function () {
    $(this).select2();
});
```

Comment: awesome, it works! however, it causes the select length look weird. short at the first one and getting longer and longer at the next one. any idea?

Comment: You don't need the `each()` call here. `$('select[id^="select"]').select2()` will work fine

Answer (score -1):

Group them with a class:

```
<div class="select">
    <select id="select1"></select>
    <select id="select2"></select>
    <select id="select3"></select>
</div>
```

Then with jQuery:

```
$.map($('.select').children(), function (ele, i) {
    doYourThing($(ele));
  });
```